# Trying to delete a property in an array that is also within in array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested, state

I'm trying to add functionality to my application for deleting values in the list array of the following state

```
shoeList : [ 
  {name: 'Nike', 
   list : [
    {type: 'boots', revenue: '1000000', gender: 'mens', price: '49.99', id: 3},
    {type: 'shoes', revenue: '13280100', gender: 'womens', price: '99.99', id: 2}
    ]
  }
],
```

I understand that ids have to be equal in order for a deletion to occur. Right now i'm trying to access the appropriate row to be deleted(type, revenue, gender, and price) but am not sure how to access properties in an array thats within an array.

Here is the code i have so far

```
deleteShoe = (id) => 
  {
    let shoeList = this.state.shoeList.filter(shoe =>{
      return (
        shoe.list.filter(shoeid =>{
          return shoeid.id !== id
        }
        )
      )
    });
this.setState({
  shoeList: shoeList
})
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't and can't understand why. The only reason I can think of is that filter can't be nested but if so how would I go about implementing this. Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You're just missing reassignment of `shoe.list` with updated list of shoes after filtering.

```
deleteShoe = (id) => {
    const { shoeList } = this.state;
    const newShoeList = shoeList.map(shoe => {
      shoe.list = shoe.list.filter(shoeid => shoeid.id !== id)
      return shoe;
    });
    this.setState({
      shoeList: newShoeList
    })
}
```

This should remove appropriate shoe id and reassign your `shoe.list` with newly filtered shoes list.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because `this.setState` is asynchronous, when you're updating the state based on the previous state is best to pass a function, instead of an object... Something like this `this.setState ((prevState) => {//Do your logic and return your state})`.